# How does UltraVNC achieve "Server Monitor Blanking"

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, multiple-monitors, vnc

UltraVNC is able to blank the monitor of the computer being remotely accessed. My question is, how is this possible?

In my understanding, due to the nature of the Windows OS, remote desktop applications are limited to remotely displaying only snapshots of the current physical screen. I believe UltraVNC is also subject to this limitation. But, somehow, they have found a way to disconnect the physical screen whilst remotely displaying what it should normally display.

Any idea how this is done?

Answer (score 0):

Use the force, read the [source](http://ultravnc.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/ultravnc/UltraVNC%20Project%20Root/UltraVNC/).

Comment: Ok, Thanks for the advise ;) Ironically, I looked at the source after your comment. It appears that they simply power off the monitor (See vncDesktop::SetBlankMonitor). And from the following thread (http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/31189375/blank-the-monitor-screen.aspx), they do exactly what I thought is dirty and didn't want to do: power off the monitor each time a new key or mouse event is received.

Comment: But then, the following thread, http://forum.ultravnc.info/viewtopic.php?p=54949, seems to contradict all this. It seems to imply that there is a technique by which you  put a layer window on top of the display, and capture the window below. Not sure how this works.